# php and sql together in the func of a class

Tags: php

this piece of code was given in a book.

```
$query="select name, description from widget where widgetid=$widgetid";  
$rs=mysql_query($query,$this->connect);  

if(!is_resource($rs))  
    throw new exception("could not execute the query");  

if(!mysql_num_rows($rs))  
    throw new exception("found no rows");  

$data=mysql_fetch_array($rs);  
$this->name=data['name'];  
$this->description['description'];
```

what is meant by the last two lines of the code?

Comment: Should that last line be `$this->description = data['description'];`?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Pascal did it for you this time, but next time try it yourself. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third line before the end :

```
$data=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

will fetch one row of the resultset that corresponds to the SQL query, and assign it, as an array, to `$data`.

See the documentation of [**`mysql_fetch_array()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for more details.

The next line :

```
$this->name=data['name'];
```

is not valid PHP, and will result in a `Parse Error`.

Instead, to be valid, it should be written like this :

```
$this->name=$data['name'];
```

Note the additionnal `$`, that means that `$data` is a variable.

It will assign the value of the `name` item of the `$data` array to the `name` attribute of the current object.

Basically : the `name` attribute of the current instance of your class will contain the value of the `name` column of the row you've fetched from database.

And, finally, the last line :

```
$this->description['description'];
```

doesn't do anything : you access the `description` item of the attribute `description` of the current object -- that attribute being an array ; but you don't do anything with it.

I suppose it should be written :

```
$this->description = $data['description'];
```

In which case it would do the same kind of thing as the previous line -- with the `description` item/field/attribute.

---

Considering your question, **you should take a look at the PHP manual**, and, especially, at the following sections :

- [**Arrays**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [**Objects**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)
- [**Classes and objects**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 0):

- `$this` refers to the current instance of the class.
- `->` tells PHP to refer to a member of the instance.
- `name` is the referred member.

So, the following line:

```
$this->name = $data['name'];
```

Sets the property `name` of the current instance (`$this`) to whatever value held by the array `$data` at index `name`.

For more information, you can read the OOP Basics in the PHP Documentation:

> [PHP Documentation: Classes and Objects - The Basics](http://php.net/oop5.basic)
>   [PHP Documentation: Classes and Objects - Properties](http://php.net/oop5.properties)

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, "data" is the array that hold the results of your query.

- In your query you are retrieving "name" and "description" from the table "widget".
- $this->name = data['name'] is assigning the value of name from the query to the name property or variable in your instance. $this refers to the current instance

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Considering this code is from book, I think it is part of some method where widget name and description is fetched from DB and updated on class properties.

BTW, if last two lines are as is as you pasted then there is some print mistake :)